# after submitting the form it redirects to action page but do not save data in database

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["testid"])&&isset($_POST["testtime"])&&isset($_POST["testdate"])&&isset($_POST["year"])&&isset($_POST["branch"]))
{
 $tid = $_POST["testid"];
 $ttime = $_POST["testtime"];
 $tdate = $_POST["testdate"];
 $year = $_POST["year"];
 $branch = $_POST["branch"];
 
 
 $query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_create_test";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
 
 $bool = true;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
 { 
  $tidTemp= $row['fld_test_id'];
  if($tidTemp==$tid)
   {
  
   $bool=false;
   echo '<script>alert("This Test id is already Assigned");</script>' ;
   echo '<script>window.location.assign("")</script>'; 
   }
  
 } 
 
 if($bool)
 { 
  $query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_create_test(fld_test_id,fld_test_time,fld_test_date,fld_year,fld_branch) 
       VALUES('$tid','$ttime','$tdate','$year','$branch')";

  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
  if($result2)
  {
   $_SESSION['test_id']=$tid;
   header("location: enter_questions.php");

  }
 }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Area</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">WELCOME TO ADMIN AREA</h1>
<div style="width:50%; float:left;" >
<h2><u>Test Creation Section</u></h2>
<div style="padding:20px;">
<form method="post" action="enter_questions.php">
<label>Test id:<br><input type="text" name="testid" required></label></br>
<label>Test Time:<br><input type="time" name="testtime" required></label></br>
<label>Test Date:<br><input type="date" name="testdate" required></label></br>
<label>Year:<br><input type="text" name="year" required></label></br>
<label>Branch:<br><input type="text" name="branch" required></label></br>


<br><button type="submit" >Next</button>
</form>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The data is not saved in DB after clicking on next but it redirects to `enter_questions` page. I need to store data in DB so as to proceed. I am experienced in codeigniter but never did work on core PHP before.

Comment: enter_questions.php is the same page where your form is?

Comment: no no its a different page

Comment: is this php code from `enter_questions.php`?

Comment: Try moving the "update code" to the enter_questions.php file

Comment: @rafael you mean whole php code to enter_questions.php?

Comment: if i use $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] in the action parameter of form then??

Answer (score 0):

Every form has a action, in your case you are saying to the form "When i click the button go to enter_questions.php". The form is going to listen you instruction and go to this file but nothing is there to do. If you want to run the code in the same place where your form is you can leave the `action=''` and make a submit button like this.

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Click Me!'>
```

And know comes the question, How do you know when the button is clicked and run the code you want? Well you can do it this way.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //run your code
}
```

You can read this article [how forms work](http://www.simfatic.com/forms/help/v40/how_does_an_html_form_work_.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include("includes/connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["testid"])&&isset($_POST["testtime"])&&isset($_POST["testdate"])&&isset($_POST["year"])&&isset($_POST["branch"])) {
    $tid = $_POST["testid"];
    $ttime = $_POST["testtime"];
    $tdate = $_POST["testdate"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $branch = $_POST["branch"];
    /// optimized code
    if($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `fld_test_id` FROM tbl_create_test WHERE `fld_test_id`='$tid' LIMIT 1"))) {
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tbl_create_test (fld_test_id,fld_test_time,fld_test_date,fld_year,fld_branch)
                         VALUES ('$tid','$ttime','$tdate','$year','$branch')")) {
            $_SESSION['test_id']=$tid;
            header("location: enter_questions.php");
            die;
        }
    }
    /// id exists or not insert record
    echo '<script>alert("This Test id is already Assigned");</script>'  ;
    echo '<script>window.location.assign("")</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the `action`  from `form`. If it create problem then check your connection code in this `include("includes/connection.php");`

Edit2: I have try your code with `mysql` and it save the data into database

```html
<?php
session_start();
 mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('error');
 mysql_select_db('dbp');
if(isset($_POST["testid"])&&isset($_POST["testtime"])&&isset($_POST["testdate"])&&isset($_POST["year"])&&isset($_POST["branch"]))
{
    $tid = $_POST["testid"];
    $ttime = $_POST["testtime"];
    $tdate = $_POST["testdate"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $branch = $_POST["branch"];


    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_create_test";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1);

    $bool = true;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {   
        $tidTemp= $row['fld_test_id'];
        if($tidTemp==$tid)
            {

            $bool=false;
            echo '<script>alert("This Test id is already Assigned");</script>'  ;
            echo '<script>window.location.assign("")</script>'; 
            }

    }   

    if($bool==true)
    {   


        $query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_create_test(fld_test_id,fld_test_time,fld_test_date,fld_year,fld_branch) VALUES('$tid','$ttime','$tdate','$year','$branch')";

        $result2 = mysql_query($query2)or die('error in insertion');
        if($result2)
        {
            $_SESSION['test_id']=$tid;
            header("location: enter_questions.php");

        }
    }

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Area</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">WELCOME TO ADMIN AREA</h1>
<div style="width:50%; float:left;" >
<h2><u>Test Creation Section</u></h2>
<div style="padding:20px;">
<form method="post" >
<label>Test id:<br><input type="text" name="testid" required></label></br>
<label>Test Time:<br><input type="time" name="testtime" required></label></br>
<label>Test Date:<br><input type="date" name="testdate" required></label></br>
<label>Year:<br><input type="text" name="year" required></label></br>
<label>Branch:<br><input type="text" name="branch" required></label></br>


<br><button type="submit" >Next</button>
</form>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: after removing action it redirects to same form rather than going to create_question.php

Comment: @Pallavi There's absolutely no difference between those two forms.

Comment: @PratikAgarwal If that's happening, it probably means the `INSERT` query is getting an error, so the redirect isn't being done. You should print the error mesage when that happens, with `echo mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: Did you get the solution?